# why my context on glide return error nullable in logcat?

Tags: android, android-glide

i'm new on using glide. i try to load image from external storage, but i got error in logcat :

[image]

there is my class of recycleview adapter which use glide for load image :

```
List<TourModel> mItems;
    private Context mContext;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView mIvMain,mIvStar1,mIvStar2,mIvStar3,mIvStar4,mIvStar5;
        public TextView mTvTitle,mTvPrice;
        public RelativeLayout mLayoutContainer;
        public ViewHolder(View mItemView) {
            super(mItemView);
            mIvMain = (ImageView) mItemView.findViewById(R.id.listFragmentMain_IvMain);
            mIvStar1= (ImageView) mItemView.findViewById(R.id.listFragmentMain_IvStar1);
            mIvStar2= (ImageView) mItemView.findViewById(R.id.listFragmentMain_IvStar2);
            mIvStar3= (ImageView) mItemView.findViewById(R.id.listFragmentMain_IvStar3);
            mIvStar4= (ImageView) mItemView.findViewById(R.id.listFragmentMain_IvStar4);
            mIvStar5= (ImageView) mItemView.findViewById(R.id.listFragmentMain_IvStar5);
            mTvTitle = (TextView) mItemView.findViewById(R.id.listFragmentMain_TvTitle);
            mTvPrice = (TextView) mItemView.findViewById(R.id.listFragmentMain_TvPrice);
            mLayoutContainer = (RelativeLayout)mItemView.findViewById(R.id.listFragmentMain_LayoutContainer);
        }
    }

    public TourListRvAdapter(Context mContext,List<TourModel> mModel) {
        this.mItems = mModel;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup mViewGroup, int i) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(mViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_main, mViewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder mViewHold = new ViewHolder(mView);
        return mViewHold;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder mViewHolder, int position) {
        final TourModel mItems=this.mItems.get(position);
        mViewHolder.mTvTitle.setText(mItems.getTitle());
        mViewHolder.mTvPrice.setText(mItems.getPrice() + "");

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(Utility.LoadFileImg(mItems.getImage()))
                .into(mViewHolder.mIvMain);
    }
```

and there is my fragment activity which call recycleview adapter and add variable context to it.

```
Public class TourListFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = TourListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private final Context mContext = getActivity();

    private int position;
    private List<TourModel> mListItem;

    private RecyclerView mRecycleView;

    private TourListRvAdapter mTouListAdapter;

    public static TourListFragment newInstance(int position) {
        TourListFragment f = new TourListFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(VariableConstants.POSITION, position);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        position = getArguments().getInt(VariableConstants.POSITION);
        TourDAO mDao = new TourDAO(getContext());
        mListItem = mDao.getAllDataReturnModel();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e(TAG, "" + position);

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            mRecycleView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragmentMain_RvTourList);
            mRecycleView .setHasFixedSize(true); // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(mContext); // use a linear layout manager
            mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            mTouListAdapter = new TourListRvAdapter(mContext,mListItem);
            mRecycleView.setAdapter(mTouListAdapter);

            //iewCompat.setElevation(rootView, 50);
            return rootView;

    }
}
```

I dont know why my variable mContext return null , anyone can help me ? please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mViewHolder.itemView.getContext()`, which is the same context you are using in `onCreateViewHolder` to inflate your view , instead of keeping a reference to in your Adapter. `mContext` is null because you are initializing the member

```
private final Context mContext = getActivity();
```

The Fragment didn't go through its lifecycle at that time and getActivity() is returning null

Comment: *which is the same context you are using in onCreateViewHolder* ... so still null ... as the main problem is `private final Context mContext = getActivity();` in the fragment

Comment: maybe is poor worded @Selvin. `onCreateViewHolder` is using the ViewGroup to inflate the view. That;s what I meant

Comment: i already changed it , thank you, your code is work :) @Blackbelt